# Hearing an deep hum sound, is it the reverse thrust deployment noise?

Tags: airbus-a320

I have been hearing a deep hum sound from where I live which sounds like an Airbus 320 Family Reverse Thrust deployment noise. NOTE: However I live 15KMS+ from the Airport but the runway approach path is almost above my house.
The sound is almost the same at 5:26 in the below video. I would like to know if it is reverse thrust or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Very few civil airliners have been certified for thrust reversal in flight, and those that were rarely used it because of the adverse effect on passenger comfort. I'd guess the sound you hear is something else, but I've no idea what.

Comment: I don’t hear any specific “deep hum” at 5:26. I think I I hear either spoilers or thrust reversers deploy at 5:*3*6, but that wouldn’t happen in the air 15km away. Lowering flaps or gear increases drag, which makes a lot of extra noise until the plane slows down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I grew up under the northbound final approach path for Oakland International Airport and have experienced what you describe here, where a jet shedding altitude and getting lined up for straight-in with its engines throttled back suddenly begins to produce a very loud, low-pitched "moaning" noise about 15 miles out from the threshold. As near as I could determine, that was the point in the approach where the gear went down and/or the flaps were extended all the way- so the moaning was produced by vortex shedding & turbulence from the gear and the flaps.